# Change JPA entity @OneToMany to fetch from JAX-RS Service

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs

First, my class:

```
public class Person {

    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> address; 
    ...
}
```

My problem is that I want to change from where I am getting the data, first I was getting from database and now I need to fetch from a service, but this probably will break my entity, because I will not have @OneToMany List but a List holding all the address's id.

There is a easier way to change JPA relationship to JAX-RS service? How I will fetch the data now? Maybe a AddressService where I pass all ids and the service return a List, can anyone here help me with a less painful solution?

Comment: JPA is meant to deal with database and not web services. If you are dealign with web services, why use jpa in first place ?

Comment: Well, because I need to keep the persons on my database and the address I need to fetch from other place now. This is just a simple case that I have.

Comment: If you break a monolithic project into microservices projects, you probably will deal with my problem here.

Comment: would be really interesting to know about this kind of stuff. I do not have idea about microservices

Comment: A sample: https://github.com/ewolff/microservice/